# Laravel 6 can not found vendor class from the fast-tuned package that was released for the Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, composer-php, firebird, classnotfound

I am trying to use Firebird 3.0 from Laravel 6.0 and I am following https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fbdevgd-en/html/fbdevgd30-php-Laravel-crt-project.html where the package https://github.com/sim1984/laravel-firebird is suggested. Unfortunately, this package is intended for Laravel 5.7 (or maybe it has not been published in composer repositories) that is why I received the following message while I was trying to install this package:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Could not find a matching version of package sim1984/laravel-firebird. Check the package spelling, your version con
straint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (dev).
```

So, I had this great ide to to fine tune this package that is why I forked it as https://github.com/alex153490/laravel-firebird, I changed the version requirements in its composer.json. I hope that there is not other work to be done to ensure the compatibility with Laravel 6. After that I added this git repository in the composer.json of my Laravel project:

```
 "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "alex153490/laravel-firebird",
                "version": "master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/alex153490/laravel-firebird.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

Now the package was installed OK. I have created one model file in my Laravel project and I added the import

```
use Firebird\Eloquent\Model;
```

as was suggested by the original description of the original package.

But now I started to receive error

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Class 'Firebird\Eloquent\Model' not found
```

while trying to call this model class from the simple rest API controller of my project.

Why is this class not found error - the package was installed without error, the package sits inside the vendor folder of my project and all seems to be OK. I have checked the possible issues from the checklist https://dev.to/dechamp/php---how-to-fix-class--not-found-error-1gp9 , including I regenerated the autoload file for my project, but of no help.

What did I do wrong? Why it is so hard to make class visible from my package inside the vendor directory?

p.s. when I tried to use suggested Laravel-Firebird packages for Laravel 6 (https://packagist.org/packages/harrygulliford/laravel-firebird or https://github.com/KKSzymanowski/laravel-6-firebird) I always got the exception event for the most basic select statement:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: -901 Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -901 feature is not supported (SQL: select * from "MY_TABLE")
```

It seems to me that the authors of the package has just provided data for the Firebird-specific grammar (includind the statements for the system data), but their ignored that Firebird can have some features missing for use from Laravel.

Comment: Are you sure using reverse slash is okay ? `Use Firebird\Eloquent\Model;` Compare with the primary slash used instead in the example you linked `use Your/Class/Here;` Using reverse-slash instead of primary slash is a habit in FILE PATHS on CP/M -> MS-DOS -> MS-Windows, but it is not so in the program sources!

Comment: The package you forked, was forked from https://github.com/jacquestvanzuydam/laravel-firebird, which is no longer maintained and recommends using https://github.com/KKSzymanowski/laravel-6-firebird (which seems to be for Laravel 6).

Comment: Of course, I tried package by KKSzymanowski, but it gave the the same error message (I will specify tomorrow) that gave the generic Firebird-Laravel packages that had this bug about not handling the autoincrement feature that is required by Laravel and hence I wonder whether the have been used or tested at all. KkS package has not this autoincrement/sequence handling code and that is why I have doubts that it is anything more than initial pet project. I have no evidence of contrary.

Comment: The author does say _"I do not create my own Firebird databases, only read from existing ones so the INSERT and UPDATE support may be spotty."_. However, I don't see anything in your question to suggest that `Firebird\Eloquent\Model` even exists. It is not a class in the driver, so I guess it should be a class in your application.

Comment: This class exists, e.g. https://github.com/sim1984/laravel-firebird/tree/master/src/Firebird/Eloquent I can not do even the single select from one table. My guess is that Laravel Eloquent, while building the internal schema/class, expect the autoincrement field and that is why even the schema building even for the select operation fails. sim1984 package is the most thoightful one, it has some insight in documentation and universal example (even with associations) is provided in the Firebird documentation (see my references). Hope that community gather around this package.

Comment: Laravel is the most popular PHP framework and one of the most popular frameworks (also backends for SPA React, Angular, Vue.js applications) overall. I am aware about Russian community around Firebird and Yii, but there is always temptation to go with the majority, i.e. with Laravel.

Comment: Interesting thing is that sim1984 is Russian tech-writer making original (in Russian) documentati onto Firebird and making some articles about connecting to FB from different articles. I wonder if he forked Laravel to fix some bugs that prevented articles from working. Anyway, i believe one has to start with fixing `use Firebird\Eloquent\Model;` line or with proving it matches both PHP formal syntax and PHP implementation.

Comment: Granted, this example, which probably was the reason of that fork, uses exactly reversed slashes: https://github.com/sim1984/phpfbexample/blob/master/app/Product.php

Comment: But that sim1984 Product.php example has `use Firebird\Eloquent\Model;` - the same slashes as I already have. Besides, I tried to write `use Firebird/Eloquent/Model;` and it is not even a valid PHP code!

Comment: you did not say you tried before, so i reiterated, and the **dev.to** article you linked to uses forward slashes, do they violate PHP syntax?.. Then, if you use Windows OS maybe you can try SysInternals Process Monitor to track PHP process file i/o and see if it tries to find sources for that class, and if it does - under which names and in which folders

Comment: Here were his articles on that package, you may try to read them using services like www.translate.ru - 1) https://habrahabr.ru/post/311446/ 2) https://habr.com/ru/post/312874/ 3) https://habr.com/ru/post/317458/ but i am not sure there would be somethign about the error you see

Comment: I tried other slashes just now, upon your suggestion, that is why, it was not mentioned in my post. Thanks for articles, I know Russian very well.

Comment: I inserted in my scripti `var_dump(get_declared_classes());` and the dump contains lot of classes, including Eloquent classes, but it does not contain word `Firebird`, so, there is problems with the autoloading of my package. apache-php error log does not contain any hints. So, now I am narrowing down my investigation of the loadability of my laravel-firebird package. Currently I have no idea how to debug this.

Comment: OK, now I am seeing into vendor/composer of my Laravel project and there is installed.json with firebird-laravel entries  `"version": "master", "version_normalized": "9999999-dev",` but Firebird classes do not appear in autoload_psr4.php or autoload_real.php or any other autload files. So, the going into deeper...

Comment: I added p.s. section with the error exception for the "standard" Laravel-6-Firebird packages.